# MySQL delete duplicate rows except NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table (Final) in my db and i want to delete all the duplicate rows except
those who have a NULL value;
I tried the above :

```
 DELETE FROM Final 
  WHERE event_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(event_id) AS MinID 
                           FROM (SELECT * FROM Final) as x 
                          GROUP BY event_name
                            AND event_name IS NOT NULL)
```

but didn't work.

**edit**

my table seems like:

id | Coral
1 | NULL
2 | 1
3 | 1  <- DELETE
4 | 2
5 | NULL <- STAY as it is
6 | 1  <-DELETE

Comment: because u didn't close the subquery's parenthesis.

Comment: what is the column that is duplicate in each group?

Comment: event_name is the column.. this column maybe have 1,2,1,4,NULL,NUll,2.. And i want to have 1,2,4,NULL,NUll

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but if I may, I would recommend using backticks `\`` for table names and column names, to avoid conflicting with mysql keywords or potential future keywords. i.e. `DELETE FROM \`Final\``

Answer (score 1):

how about joining the tables?

```
DELETE  a
FROM    Final a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Event_name, MIN(Event_ID) MIN_ID
            FROM    Final
            WHERE   Event_name IS NOT NULL
            GROUP   BY Event_name
        ) b ON a.Event_name = b.Event_name AND
                a.Event_ID = b.MIN_ID
WHERE   a.Event_name IS NOT NULL AND 
        b.Event_name IS NULL
```

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your solution.. I only have one table (Final)

Comment: this is the same with your solution that uses subquery. try to execute the statement above, but please do some backup first.

Comment: can you give sample records so I can modify the query? maybe 4-5 records on the table.

Comment: What happens if you execute the statement above?

Comment: OMG it works like a charm!! Thank u so much @JW. Sorry for being late!!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `AND event_name IS NOT NULL` part to the main subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Final 
  WHERE event_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(event_id) AS MinID 
                           FROM (SELECT * FROM Final) as x 
                          GROUP BY event_name)
    AND event_name IS NOT NULL
```